# Getting NSException Error Crash App

Tags: ios, firebase, swift4

so I got an NSException error even though my code had nothing wrong. Before i getting NSException i add a fileprivate function [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhinI.png)

```
fileprivate func uploadToFirebaseStorageUsingImage(image: UIImage) {
    let imageName = UUID().uuidString
    let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child("message_images").child("\(imageName).jpg")

    if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2) {

        ref.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Failed to upload image:", error!)
                return
            }

            ref.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                guard let downloadURL = url else{
                    print("an error occured")
                    return
                }

                let imageUrl = downloadURL.absoluteString
                self.sendMessageWithImageUrl(imageUrl, image: image)

            })
        })
    }
}
```

And the full error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F0kc.png)

```
2018-08-23 14:48:04.985710+0700 nextstore[33702:369585] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<nextstore.User 0x60800011f920> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d251e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001093ba031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d250b9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001086c8b47 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   Foundation                          0x0000000108726c02 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:] + 283
    5   nextstore                           0x000000010724da39 _T09nextstore18MessagesControllerC28fetchUserAndSetupNavBarTitleyyFySo12DataSnapshotCcfU_ + 713
    6   nextstore                           0x000000010724db1d _T09nextstore18MessagesControllerC28fetchUserAndSetupNavBarTitleyyFySo12DataSnapshotCcfU_TA + 13
    7   nextstore                           0x00000001072338d2 _T0So12DataSnapshotCIegx_ABIeyBy_TR + 66
    8   nextstore                           0x000000010730d0e6 __71-[FIRDatabaseQuery observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock:withCancelBlock:]_block_invoke + 118
    9   nextstore                           0x000000010730d5c8 __92-[FIRDatabaseQuery observeSingleEventOfType:andPreviousSiblingKeyWithBlock:withCancelBlock:]_block_invoke + 184
    10  nextstore                           0x00000001072ebc1a __43-[FChildEventRegistration fireEvent:queue:]_block_invoke.68 + 122
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010da737ab _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010da747ec _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010da7f8cf _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 628
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109ce7c99 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109cabea6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2342
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109cab30b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ef06a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010ad94057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    19  nextstore                           0x000000010726e5c7 main + 55
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010daf1955 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

There isn't any error in my code . But when i run with simulator , once it opened the app it's crashing right away
Is there any solution with my problem that i have thank you

**EDIT**

My User class is like this:

```
 class User: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: "[< nextstore.User 0x60800011f920 > setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name." That's the important part of the error. What's the class `User`? Is it a `UIView(Controller)`? Did you have an IBOutlet named `name` in it that you renamed of removed? Did you look for that error?

Comment: Put a debugger and try to find out the line it is crashing. The error is not in this code it's somewhere else. It says `User` class is not key value coding-compliant for the key `name`.

Comment: i use programmatically storyboard with MVC concept , so i dont use storyboard . And User is a class model . basically i dont know where the error is , because there isn't any error

Comment: What's the class `User`? What's its superclass? Do you have somewhere a call to `name` in it?

Comment: In User Class i got this code : 
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?
    
    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    }
}

Comment: {_T09nextstore18MessagesControllerC28fetchUserAndSetupNavBarTitleyyFySo12DataSnapshotCcfU_} Is there a method called **fetchUserAndSetupNavBar..** in **MessagesController** ?

Comment: yes there is fetchUserAndSetupNavBarTitle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not related to this function. The stack trace states that somewhere you are calling KVC method `setValuesForKeys`. There is the place where the error occurs.

To make a class key-value compliant you have to add the `@objc dynamic` attributes to each affected property

```
class User: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var id: String?
    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    @objc dynamic var email: String?
    @objc dynamic var profileImageUrl: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String
        self.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
    }
}
```

Alternatively omit all `@objc` attributes and add `@objcMembers` in front of the class.

```
@objcMembers
class User: NSObject {
    dynamic var id: String?
    dynamic ...
```

Basically you are discouraged from using these KVC methods in Swift anyway.

Comment: so i should add '@objcMembers' in all my class swift file , and erase '@objc' in all my function ?

Comment: No, if `@objcMembers` is specified all  `@objc` attributes of the properties (only) in this class can be omitted. I recommend to look for a native Swift solution without KVC and NSObject inherited classes.

Comment: Finally i know what you mean. I try your source code and it's work , my app isn't crash anymore. Thank you for the answer @vadian